# adding and incrementing date and time (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, time, increment

The below is a table that is meant to show when a media will play. so basically it has a start time (`starts`), the length of the track (`clip_length`), and when it ends (`ends` = `starts + clip_length`), and finally the position of the track.

```
|starts              | ends                 |position   |file_id| clip_length
|2013-08-30 22:00:00 | 2013-08-30 22:03:08  |0          |16     |00:03:08.081768
|2013-08-30 22:03:08 | 2013-08-30 22:06:33  |1          |17     |00:03:25.436485
|2013-08-30 22:06:33 | 2013-08-30 22:09:07  |2          |7      |00:02:33.79968
|2013-08-30 22:09:07 | 2013-08-30 22:12:21  |3          |3      |00:03:14.020273
|2013-08-30 22:12:21 | 2013-08-30 22:15:31  |4          |8      |00:03:10.466689
```

what i want to do is to add a record, at say `position =2` , shown bellow. I have been able to increment the positions, how ever the problem lies with the fact that the times are all messed up.

```
|starts              | ends                 |position   |file_id|clip_length
|2013-08-30 22:00:00 | 2013-08-30 22:03:08  |0          |16     |00:03:08.081768
|2013-08-30 22:03:08 | 2013-08-30 22:06:33  |1          |17     |00:03:25.436485
|2013-08-30 22:06:33 | 2013-08-30 22:09:07  |2          |7      |00:02:33.79968
|2013-08-30 22:06:33 | 2013-08-30 22:11:03  |3          |1      |00:04:30.006958
|2013-08-30 22:09:07 | 2013-08-30 22:12:21  |4          |3      |00:03:14.020273
|2013-08-30 22:12:21 | 2013-08-30 22:15:31  |5          |8      |00:03:10.466689
```

so it possible to use the first start time.. as point 00, and add `clip_length` to `starts` and save in `ends`, for the first one. then for the second one use the first `ends` value as the starts and do this recursively till the end (following the positions) .

thanks in advance..

Comment: Struggling to understand what you want. A running total of the intervals?

Comment: basically I want to add the 'clip_length" field to the 'start' field, and save it in the same row in the 'ends' field. then in the next row. use the previous time the song ended as the start time for the up comming song.

Comment: Side note: If these are local times and the app runs in a time zone that has DST, then you will have errors during the transitions.

Comment: well, the time shown here is at GMT time.. so the system as already converted it to GMT time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2929d/2)

```
update clip c
set
    starts = s.starts,
    ends = s.ends
from (
    select
        starts,
        starts + clip_length as ends,
        file_id,
        position
    from (
        select
            '2013-08-30 22:00:00'::timestamp
            + sum(clip_length) over(order by position)
            - clip_length as starts,
            clip_length,
            file_id,
            position
        from clip
    ) s
) s
where c.file_id = s.file_id
```

Comment: hey, i dont think i understand well. When i executed it, it changes all the values to sum(clip_length) for the 'ends' value and sum(clip_length) - last clip length as the 'starts' value. For all the rows its the same value

Answer (score 3):

Your data model is pretty borked. You're storing at least two pieces of redundant information. You need `starts` and `file_id` and any one of `clip_length`, `ends` or `position`; they can each be calculated from each other.

Right now you are storing *redundant* data, which creates the problem you now have where the data is not internally consistent, it has conflicts within its self.

In this case it sounds like `position` is trusted and the others aren't. Here's what I'd do:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT min(starts) FROM Sometable)
    + COALESCE(
       sum(clip_length) OVER all_rows_but_last,
       INTERVAL '0' second
    )
  AS starts,
  (SELECT min(starts) FROM Sometable)
    + COALESCE(
       sum(clip_length) OVER all_rows_but_last,
       INTERVAL '0' second
    ) + clip_length
  AS ends, 
  position, 
  clip_length
FROM Sometable
WINDOW all_rows_but_last AS (ORDER BY position ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING);
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ca5fa/1

The principle here is to find the lowest start - the one known to be valid - and *ignore* the following ends and starts as redundant and useless. Instead, add the *running total* of the previous durations as the start, and the same running total plus the current interval as the end.

You'll notice that this isn't an update. That's because I think you should actually:

- change `position` to a floating point value or large integer so you don't need to re-number when you insert an entry. If you put something between `1` and `2` give it position `0.5`. Or start with `10000`, `20000` etc so you can insert `15000`.
- Get rid of the `ends` column completely. calculate it from `starts` + `clip_length`
- Move `starts` to a separate table where it's stored only once, for the series of segments. Calculate clip start times on the fly from the sum of the lengths of previous clips since the start.
- Re-define the current table as a view over the two tables described above.

That's making a lot of guesses about your data and how you're using it, but you haven't said much about what you're doing.

Comment: :) , well sadly  i don't not have control over the database(cannot remove columns). Not the design, no data dictionary . Its a third-party application. that I'm trying to develop an API for.

Comment: oh and the Field_id is not very relevant. its auto generated

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as (
    select
        '2013-08-30 22:00:00'::timestamp
         + sum(clip_length) over(order by position) as ends,
         file_id
    from clip
)
update clip as cl set
    starts = c.ends - cl.clip_length,
    ends = c.ends
from cte as c
where cl.file_id = c.file_id;
```

[**=>sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2929d/14)

Actually, you could live without start and end time in your table at all. You can remove this columns from your table and create function like this:

```
create or replace function clip_layout(_starts timestamp)
returns table(
    starts timestamp, ends timestamp,
    "position" int, file_id int,clip_length interval
)
as
$$
with cte as (
    select
        _starts + sum(clip_length) over(order by position) as ends,
        file_id, clip_length, position
    from clip
)
select
    ends - clip_length as starts,
    ends, position,
    file_id, clip_length
from cte
$$
language sql;
```

So you can see start/end times starting from anytime:

```
select * from clip_layout('2013-08-30 22:00:00'::timestamp)
```

[**=>sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bae1a/1)